Solving high dimensional nonlinear algebraic equation numerically
I would like to solve an algebraic equation A=f(A) whose argument A is a large 3D matrix. Ideally, I would not like to flatten the system of equations, before feeding into FindRoot because f(A) involves convolutions, which are much faster done numerically on the matrices. Is this possible using FindRoot without rewriting a Newton-Raphson solver explicitly?
Specifically, I am trying to solve
FindRoot[
 SArr == CenterArray[-(g^2/\[Beta]) ListConvolve[DqArr, 1./(1./G0Arr - SArr), {{-1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}], 
   G0Arr // Dimensions], {SArr, \[CapitalSigma]Arr},]

where G0Arr and the initial guess \[CapitalSigma]Arr have the same shape, and DqArr has the same rank but different shape, and g and \[Beta] are constants.
A minimal working code which does flatten the matrix into a vector, before solving is provided below
DqArr = {{{-2.491326151081656`*^-7 + 
     2.6469779601696886`*^-23 I, -3.0327313821578153`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -4.380101096930404`*^-7 + 0.` I, -5.17390868652759`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -4.150829355570194`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -2.4625350724215866`*^-7 + 
     0.` I}, {-3.0327313821578153`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -4.352731622611051`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -9.089697457992721`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -1.3508907402301672`*^-6 - 
     2.117582368135751`*^-22 I, -8.849195203262221`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -3.7262249246661584`*^-7 + 
     2.6469779601696886`*^-23 I}, {-4.380101096930404`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -9.089697457992721`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -4.997110322253366`*^-6 + 
     4.235164736271502`*^-22 I, -0.000018785591838935282` + 
     0.` I, -4.970934505176787`*^-6 + 
     0.` I, -8.344671150527775`*^-7 + 
     5.293955920339377`*^-23 I}, {-5.17390868652759`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -1.3508907402301672`*^-6 - 
     2.117582368135751`*^-22 I, -0.000018785591838935282` + 
     0.` I, -0.0007163648550175445` + 
     1.0842021724855044`*^-19 I, -0.000018759070998794447` + 
     1.6940658945086007`*^-21 I, -1.2715603814390985`*^-6 - 
     2.117582368135751`*^-22 I}, {-4.150829355570194`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -8.849195203262221`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -4.970934505176787`*^-6 + 
     0.` I, -0.000018759070998794447` + 
     1.6940658945086007`*^-21 I, -4.947563340764621`*^-6 + 
     0.` I, -8.166816077611928`*^-7 + 
     0.` I}, {-2.4625350724215866`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -3.7262249246661584`*^-7 + 
     2.6469779601696886`*^-23 I, -8.344671150527775`*^-7 + 
     5.293955920339377`*^-23 I, -1.2715603814390985`*^-6 - 
     2.117582368135751`*^-22 I, -8.166816077611928`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -3.246109741045242`*^-7 + 
     0.` I}}, {{-4.114187361244241`*^-7 + 
     1.3234889800848443`*^-23 I, -5.008334956768068`*^-7 + 
     5.293955920339377`*^-23 I, -7.233639072284214`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -8.54475445618924`*^-7 + 0.` I, -6.855023893929493`*^-7 + 
     5.293955920339377`*^-23 I, -4.06671893376573`*^-7 + 
     0.` I}, {-5.008334956768068`*^-7 + 
     5.293955920339377`*^-23 I, -7.188574850244807`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -1.5014254765768087`*^-6 + 
     0.` I, -2.2317419737198356`*^-6 + 
     0.` I, -1.461709324326809`*^-6 + 
     0.` I, -6.153964679465149`*^-7 + 
     1.3234889800848443`*^-23 I}, {-7.233639072284214`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -1.5014254765768087`*^-6 + 
     0.` I, -8.266379107086613`*^-6 + 
     2.117582368135751`*^-22 I, -0.0000312308794746585` - 
     1.6940658945086007`*^-21 I, -8.223152684650612`*^-6 + 
     0.` I, -1.3783912875033888`*^-6 + 
     2.6469779601696886`*^-23 I}, {-8.54475445618924`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -2.2317419737198356`*^-6 + 
     0.` I, -0.0000312308794746585` - 
     1.6940658945086007`*^-21 I, -0.0017288580150061335` + 
     1.0842021724855044`*^-19 I, -0.00003118708322416664` + 
     0.` I, -2.1007346961889135`*^-6 - 
     5.293955920339377`*^-23 I}, {-6.855023893929493`*^-7 + 
     5.293955920339377`*^-23 I, -1.461709324326809`*^-6 + 
     0.` I, -8.223152684650612`*^-6 + 
     0.` I, -0.00003118708322416664` + 
     0.` I, -8.184557800848152`*^-6 + 
     0.` I, -1.3490205594209672`*^-6 - 
     2.6469779601696886`*^-23 I}, {-4.06671893376573`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -6.153964679465149`*^-7 + 
     1.3234889800848443`*^-23 I, -1.3783912875033888`*^-6 + 
     2.6469779601696886`*^-23 I, -2.1007346961889135`*^-6 - 
     5.293955920339377`*^-23 I, -1.3490205594209672`*^-6 - 
     2.6469779601696886`*^-23 I, -5.361102946757346`*^-7 - 
     1.3234889800848443`*^-23 I}}, {{-6.851552031690302`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -8.340842098179467`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -1.2047567752765983`*^-6 + 
     0.` I, -1.423174148929808`*^-6 + 
     0.` I, -1.1417058900685305`*^-6 + 
     0.` I, -6.772752693123286`*^-7 + 
     0.` I}, {-8.340842098179467`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -1.1972956943168267`*^-6 + 
     0.` I, -2.501533400728777`*^-6 + 
     0.` I, -3.7194828086745648`*^-6 + 
     0.` I, -2.4353938317779373`*^-6 + 
     0.` I, -1.0249990447602403`*^-6 + 
     0.` I}, {-1.2047567752765983`*^-6 + 
     0.` I, -2.501533400728777`*^-6 + 
     0.` I, -0.000013812701657056203` + 
     0.` I, -0.00005270272758014736` + 
     0.` I, -0.00001374071607723831` + 
     0.` I, -2.296638040860545`*^-6 + 
     0.` I}, {-1.423174148929808`*^-6 + 
     0.` I, -3.7194828086745648`*^-6 + 
     0.` I, -0.00005270272758014736` + 
     0.` I, -0.025491971372427612` + 0.` I, -0.0000526297928578936` + 
     0.` I, -3.5013076705732583`*^-6 + 
     0.` I}, {-1.1417058900685305`*^-6 + 
     0.` I, -2.4353938317779373`*^-6 + 
     0.` I, -0.00001374071607723831` + 
     0.` I, -0.0000526297928578936` + 
     0.` I, -0.000013676443366206937` + 
     0.` I, -2.247726677401557`*^-6 + 
     0.` I}, {-6.772752693123286`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -1.0249990447602403`*^-6 + 
     0.` I, -2.296638040860545`*^-6 + 
     0.` I, -3.5013076705732583`*^-6 + 
     0.` I, -2.247726677401557`*^-6 + 
     0.` I, -8.929608774587834`*^-7 + 
     0.` I}}, {{-4.114187361244241`*^-7 - 
     1.3234889800848443`*^-23 I, -5.008334956768068`*^-7 - 
     5.293955920339377`*^-23 I, -7.233639072284214`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -8.54475445618924`*^-7 + 0.` I, -6.855023893929493`*^-7 - 
     5.293955920339377`*^-23 I, -4.06671893376573`*^-7 + 
     0.` I}, {-5.008334956768068`*^-7 - 
     5.293955920339377`*^-23 I, -7.188574850244807`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -1.5014254765768087`*^-6 + 
     0.` I, -2.2317419737198356`*^-6 + 
     0.` I, -1.461709324326809`*^-6 + 
     0.` I, -6.153964679465149`*^-7 - 
     1.3234889800848443`*^-23 I}, {-7.233639072284214`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -1.5014254765768087`*^-6 + 
     0.` I, -8.266379107086613`*^-6 - 
     2.117582368135751`*^-22 I, -0.0000312308794746585` + 
     1.6940658945086007`*^-21 I, -8.223152684650612`*^-6 + 
     0.` I, -1.3783912875033888`*^-6 - 
     2.6469779601696886`*^-23 I}, {-8.54475445618924`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -2.2317419737198356`*^-6 + 
     0.` I, -0.0000312308794746585` + 
     1.6940658945086007`*^-21 I, -0.0017288580150061335` - 
     1.0842021724855044`*^-19 I, -0.00003118708322416664` + 
     0.` I, -2.1007346961889135`*^-6 + 
     5.293955920339377`*^-23 I}, {-6.855023893929493`*^-7 - 
     5.293955920339377`*^-23 I, -1.461709324326809`*^-6 + 
     0.` I, -8.223152684650612`*^-6 + 
     0.` I, -0.00003118708322416664` + 
     0.` I, -8.184557800848152`*^-6 + 
     0.` I, -1.3490205594209672`*^-6 + 
     2.6469779601696886`*^-23 I}, {-4.06671893376573`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -6.153964679465149`*^-7 - 
     1.3234889800848443`*^-23 I, -1.3783912875033888`*^-6 - 
     2.6469779601696886`*^-23 I, -2.1007346961889135`*^-6 + 
     5.293955920339377`*^-23 I, -1.3490205594209672`*^-6 + 
     2.6469779601696886`*^-23 I, -5.361102946757346`*^-7 + 
     1.3234889800848443`*^-23 I}}, {{-2.491326151081656`*^-7 - 
     2.6469779601696886`*^-23 I, -3.0327313821578153`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -4.380101096930404`*^-7 + 0.` I, -5.17390868652759`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -4.150829355570194`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -2.4625350724215866`*^-7 + 
     0.` I}, {-3.0327313821578153`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -4.352731622611051`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -9.089697457992721`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -1.3508907402301672`*^-6 + 
     2.117582368135751`*^-22 I, -8.849195203262221`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -3.7262249246661584`*^-7 - 
     2.6469779601696886`*^-23 I}, {-4.380101096930404`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -9.089697457992721`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -4.997110322253366`*^-6 - 
     4.235164736271502`*^-22 I, -0.000018785591838935282` + 
     0.` I, -4.970934505176787`*^-6 + 
     0.` I, -8.344671150527775`*^-7 - 
     5.293955920339377`*^-23 I}, {-5.17390868652759`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -1.3508907402301672`*^-6 + 
     2.117582368135751`*^-22 I, -0.000018785591838935282` + 
     0.` I, -0.0007163648550175445` - 
     1.0842021724855044`*^-19 I, -0.000018759070998794447` - 
     1.6940658945086007`*^-21 I, -1.2715603814390985`*^-6 + 
     2.117582368135751`*^-22 I}, {-4.150829355570194`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -8.849195203262221`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -4.970934505176787`*^-6 + 
     0.` I, -0.000018759070998794447` - 
     1.6940658945086007`*^-21 I, -4.947563340764621`*^-6 + 
     0.` I, -8.166816077611928`*^-7 + 
     0.` I}, {-2.4625350724215866`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -3.7262249246661584`*^-7 - 
     2.6469779601696886`*^-23 I, -8.344671150527775`*^-7 - 
     5.293955920339377`*^-23 I, -1.2715603814390985`*^-6 + 
     2.117582368135751`*^-22 I, -8.166816077611928`*^-7 + 
     0.` I, -3.246109741045242`*^-7 + 0.` I}}};
G0Arr = {{{0.00026221806120695063` + 9.132096056088802`*^-6 I, 
    0.00038420480406961213` + 0.000019632560501338157` I, 
    0.0016590243195173551` + 
     0.00038474728620012356` I, -0.0031986954042854928` + 
     0.0017753902359875918` I, 
    0.0016590243195173551` + 0.00038474728620012356` I, 
    0.00038420480406961213` + 
     0.000019632560501338157` I}, {0.00038420480406961213` + 
     0.000019632560501338157` I, 
    0.0006154214640650449` + 0.00005058106279201534` I, 
    0.002561455035228608` + 
     0.0065343476170139` I, -0.0017814909478848769` + 
     0.00044757780189576285` I, 
    0.002561455035228608` + 0.0065343476170139` I, 
    0.0006154214640650449` + 
     0.00005058106279201534` I}, {0.0016590243195173551` + 
     0.00038474728620012356` I, 
    0.002561455035228608` + 
     0.0065343476170139` I, -0.001623300348016125` + 
     0.0003674684922360431` I, -0.0013717502339991136` + 
     0.00025847659591489983` I, -0.001623300348016125` + 
     0.0003674684922360431` I, 
    0.002561455035228608` + 
     0.0065343476170139` I}, {-0.0031986954042854928` + 
     0.0017753902359875918` I, -0.0017814909478848769` + 
     0.00044757780189576285` I, -0.0013717502339991136` + 
     0.00025847659591489983` I, -0.0016108898926981722` + 
     0.0003615740196760342` I, -0.0013717502339991136` + 
     0.00025847659591489983` I, -0.0017814909478848769` + 
     0.00044757780189576285` I}, {0.0016590243195173551` + 
     0.00038474728620012356` I, 
    0.002561455035228608` + 
     0.0065343476170139` I, -0.001623300348016125` + 
     0.0003674684922360431` I, -0.0013717502339991136` + 
     0.00025847659591489983` I, -0.001623300348016125` + 
     0.0003674684922360431` I, 
    0.002561455035228608` + 
     0.0065343476170139` I}, {0.00038420480406961213` + 
     0.000019632560501338157` I, 
    0.0006154214640650449` + 0.00005058106279201534` I, 
    0.002561455035228608` + 
     0.0065343476170139` I, -0.0017814909478848769` + 
     0.00044757780189576285` I, 
    0.002561455035228608` + 0.0065343476170139` I, 
    0.0006154214640650449` + 
     0.00005058106279201534` I}}, {{0.0002623737383444928` + 
     6.526798372448609`*^-6 I, 
    0.00038469551764633357` + 0.00001404116826826714` I, 
    0.001701560346692065` + 
     0.00028186563718451556` I, -0.0036157861645215892` + 
     0.0014334932215780709` I, 
    0.001701560346692065` + 0.00028186563718451556` I, 
    0.00038469551764633357` + 
     0.00001404116826826714` I}, {0.00038469551764633357` + 
     0.00001404116826826714` I, 
    0.0006174506610746909` + 0.0000362484579179957` I, 
    0.004451276746846666` + 
     0.008110956245960126` I, -0.0018348493676154623` + 
     0.0003292738942473982` I, 
    0.004451276746846666` + 0.008110956245960126` I, 
    0.0006174506610746909` + 
     0.0000362484579179957` I}, {0.001701560346692065` + 
     0.00028186563718451556` I, 
    0.004451276746846666` + 
     0.008110956245960126` I, -0.0016630055874367914` + 
     0.0002688975828702291` I, -0.0013951809613295997` + 
     0.00018777972040581582` I, -0.0016630055874367914` + 
     0.0002688975828702291` I, 
    0.004451276746846666` + 
     0.008110956245960126` I}, {-0.0036157861645215892` + 
     0.0014334932215780709` I, -0.0018348493676154623` + 
     0.0003292738942473982` I, -0.0013951809613295997` + 
     0.00018777972040581582` I, -0.001649644339494305` + 
     0.0002644804933021536` I, -0.0013951809613295997` + 
     0.00018777972040581582` I, -0.0018348493676154623` + 
     0.0003292738942473982` I}, {0.001701560346692065` + 
     0.00028186563718451556` I, 
    0.004451276746846666` + 
     0.008110956245960126` I, -0.0016630055874367914` + 
     0.0002688975828702291` I, -0.0013951809613295997` + 
     0.00018777972040581582` I, -0.0016630055874367914` + 
     0.0002688975828702291` I, 
    0.004451276746846666` + 
     0.008110956245960126` I}, {0.00038469551764633357` + 
     0.00001404116826826714` I, 
    0.0006174506610746909` + 0.0000362484579179957` I, 
    0.004451276746846666` + 
     0.008110956245960126` I, -0.0018348493676154623` + 
     0.0003292738942473982` I, 
    0.004451276746846666` + 0.008110956245960126` I, 
    0.0006174506610746909` + 
     0.0000362484579179957` I}}, {{0.0002624776258373963` + 
     3.91762960408111`*^-6 I, 
    0.0003850233570115873` + 8.431880531526617`*^-6 I, 
    0.0017311505362949018` + 
     0.00017206037385286485` I, -0.00396002889556209` + 
     0.0009419817966131259` I, 
    0.0017311505362949018` + 0.00017206037385286485` I, 
    0.0003850233570115873` + 
     8.431880531526617`*^-6 I}, {0.0003850233570115873` + 
     8.431880531526617`*^-6 I, 
    0.0006188109096422206` + 0.000021796988130181255` I, 
    0.008759967672717668` + 
     0.009577258645143374` I, -0.0018722335690258528` + 
     0.00020158961790362473` I, 
    0.008759967672717668` + 0.009577258645143374` I, 
    0.0006188109096422206` + 
     0.000021796988130181255` I}, {0.0017311505362949018` + 
     0.00017206037385286485` I, 
    0.008759967672717668` + 
     0.009577258645143374` I, -0.001690572716150771` + 
     0.00016401300890634993` I, -0.001411251254850802` + 
     0.00011396558872435845` I, -0.001690572716150771` + 
     0.00016401300890634993` I, 
    0.008759967672717668` + 
     0.009577258645143374` I}, {-0.00396002889556209` + 
     0.0009419817966131259` I, -0.0018722335690258528` + 
     0.00020158961790362473` I, -0.001411251254850802` + 
     0.00011396558872435845` I, -0.0016765334634102971` + 
     0.00016127490762387608` I, -0.001411251254850802` + 
     0.00011396558872435845` I, -0.0018722335690258528` + 
     0.00020158961790362473` I}, {0.0017311505362949018` + 
     0.00017206037385286485` I, 
    0.008759967672717668` + 
     0.009577258645143374` I, -0.001690572716150771` + 
     0.00016401300890634993` I, -0.001411251254850802` + 
     0.00011396558872435845` I, -0.001690572716150771` + 
     0.00016401300890634993` I, 
    0.008759967672717668` + 
     0.009577258645143374` I}, {0.0003850233570115873` + 
     8.431880531526617`*^-6 I, 
    0.0006188109096422206` + 0.000021796988130181255` I, 
    0.008759967672717668` + 
     0.009577258645143374` I, -0.0018722335690258528` + 
     0.00020158961790362473` I, 
    0.008759967672717668` + 0.009577258645143374` I, 
    0.0006188109096422206` + 
     0.000021796988130181255` I}}, {{0.00026252960044082814` + 
     1.3061351183150884`*^-6 I, 
    0.0003851874863232472` + 2.8118249692047636`*^-6 I, 
    0.0017463349469716697` + 
     0.00005785652134203585` I, -0.004157959188081112` + 
     0.00032968798709373705` I, 
    0.0017463349469716697` + 0.00005785652134203585` I, 
    0.0003851874863232472` + 
     2.8118249692047636`*^-6 I}, {0.0003851874863232472` + 
     2.8118249692047636`*^-6 I, 
    0.000619493283882884` + 7.273674690776079`*^-6 I, 
    0.016976145815864447` + 
     0.006186664355796737` I, -0.0018915028135199792` + 
     0.00006788813385777198` I, 
    0.016976145815864447` + 0.006186664355796737` I, 
    0.000619493283882884` + 
     7.273674690776079`*^-6 I}, {0.0017463349469716697` + 
     0.00005785652134203585` I, 
    0.016976145815864447` + 
     0.006186664355796737` I, -0.0017047018737215145` + 
     0.00005512792221757807` I, -0.001419426034192462` + 
     0.00003820858099774897` I, -0.0017047018737215145` + 
     0.00005512792221757807` I, 
    0.016976145815864447` + 
     0.006186664355796737` I}, {-0.004157959188081112` + 
     0.00032968798709373705` I, -0.0018915028135199792` + 
     0.00006788813385777198` I, -0.001419426034192462` + 
     0.00003820858099774897` I, -0.0016903094450067579` + 
     0.000054200031503241506` I, -0.001419426034192462` + 
     0.00003820858099774897` I, -0.0018915028135199792` + 
     0.00006788813385777198` I}, {0.0017463349469716697` + 
     0.00005785652134203585` I, 
    0.016976145815864447` + 
     0.006186664355796737` I, -0.0017047018737215145` + 
     0.00005512792221757807` I, -0.001419426034192462` + 
     0.00003820858099774897` I, -0.0017047018737215145` + 
     0.00005512792221757807` I, 
    0.016976145815864447` + 
     0.006186664355796737` I}, {0.0003851874863232472` + 
     2.8118249692047636`*^-6 I, 
    0.000619493283882884` + 7.273674690776079`*^-6 I, 
    0.016976145815864447` + 
     0.006186664355796737` I, -0.0018915028135199792` + 
     0.00006788813385777198` I, 
    0.016976145815864447` + 0.006186664355796737` I, 
    0.000619493283882884` + 
     7.273674690776079`*^-6 I}}, {{0.00026252960044082814` - 
     1.3061351183150884`*^-6 I, 
    0.0003851874863232472` - 2.8118249692047636`*^-6 I, 
    0.0017463349469716697` - 
     0.00005785652134203585` I, -0.004157959188081112` - 
     0.00032968798709373705` I, 
    0.0017463349469716697` - 0.00005785652134203585` I, 
    0.0003851874863232472` - 
     2.8118249692047636`*^-6 I}, {0.0003851874863232472` - 
     2.8118249692047636`*^-6 I, 
    0.000619493283882884` - 7.273674690776079`*^-6 I, 
    0.016976145815864447` - 
     0.006186664355796737` I, -0.0018915028135199792` - 
     0.00006788813385777198` I, 
    0.016976145815864447` - 0.006186664355796737` I, 
    0.000619493283882884` - 
     7.273674690776079`*^-6 I}, {0.0017463349469716697` - 
     0.00005785652134203585` I, 
    0.016976145815864447` - 
     0.006186664355796737` I, -0.0017047018737215145` - 
     0.00005512792221757807` I, -0.001419426034192462` - 
     0.00003820858099774897` I, -0.0017047018737215145` - 
     0.00005512792221757807` I, 
    0.016976145815864447` - 
     0.006186664355796737` I}, {-0.004157959188081112` - 
     0.00032968798709373705` I, -0.0018915028135199792` - 
     0.00006788813385777198` I, -0.001419426034192462` - 
     0.00003820858099774897` I, -0.0016903094450067579` - 
     0.000054200031503241506` I, -0.001419426034192462` - 
     0.00003820858099774897` I, -0.0018915028135199792` - 
     0.00006788813385777198` I}, {0.0017463349469716697` - 
     0.00005785652134203585` I, 
    0.016976145815864447` - 
     0.006186664355796737` I, -0.0017047018737215145` - 
     0.00005512792221757807` I, -0.001419426034192462` - 
     0.00003820858099774897` I, -0.0017047018737215145` - 
     0.00005512792221757807` I, 
    0.016976145815864447` - 
     0.006186664355796737` I}, {0.0003851874863232472` - 
     2.8118249692047636`*^-6 I, 
    0.000619493283882884` - 7.273674690776079`*^-6 I, 
    0.016976145815864447` - 
     0.006186664355796737` I, -0.0018915028135199792` - 
     0.00006788813385777198` I, 
    0.016976145815864447` - 0.006186664355796737` I, 
    0.000619493283882884` - 
     7.273674690776079`*^-6 I}}, {{0.0002624776258373963` - 
     3.91762960408111`*^-6 I, 
    0.0003850233570115873` - 8.431880531526617`*^-6 I, 
    0.0017311505362949018` - 
     0.00017206037385286485` I, -0.00396002889556209` - 
     0.0009419817966131259` I, 
    0.0017311505362949018` - 0.00017206037385286485` I, 
    0.0003850233570115873` - 
     8.431880531526617`*^-6 I}, {0.0003850233570115873` - 
     8.431880531526617`*^-6 I, 
    0.0006188109096422206` - 0.000021796988130181255` I, 
    0.008759967672717668` - 
     0.009577258645143374` I, -0.0018722335690258528` - 
     0.00020158961790362473` I, 
    0.008759967672717668` - 0.009577258645143374` I, 
    0.0006188109096422206` - 
     0.000021796988130181255` I}, {0.0017311505362949018` - 
     0.00017206037385286485` I, 
    0.008759967672717668` - 
     0.009577258645143374` I, -0.001690572716150771` - 
     0.00016401300890634993` I, -0.001411251254850802` - 
     0.00011396558872435845` I, -0.001690572716150771` - 
     0.00016401300890634993` I, 
    0.008759967672717668` - 
     0.009577258645143374` I}, {-0.00396002889556209` - 
     0.0009419817966131259` I, -0.0018722335690258528` - 
     0.00020158961790362473` I, -0.001411251254850802` - 
     0.00011396558872435845` I, -0.0016765334634102971` - 
     0.00016127490762387608` I, -0.001411251254850802` - 
     0.00011396558872435845` I, -0.0018722335690258528` - 
     0.00020158961790362473` I}, {0.0017311505362949018` - 
     0.00017206037385286485` I, 
    0.008759967672717668` - 
     0.009577258645143374` I, -0.001690572716150771` - 
     0.00016401300890634993` I, -0.001411251254850802` - 
     0.00011396558872435845` I, -0.001690572716150771` - 
     0.00016401300890634993` I, 
    0.008759967672717668` - 
     0.009577258645143374` I}, {0.0003850233570115873` - 
     8.431880531526617`*^-6 I, 
    0.0006188109096422206` - 0.000021796988130181255` I, 
    0.008759967672717668` - 
     0.009577258645143374` I, -0.0018722335690258528` - 
     0.00020158961790362473` I, 
    0.008759967672717668` - 0.009577258645143374` I, 
    0.0006188109096422206` - 
     0.000021796988130181255` I}}, {{0.0002623737383444928` - 
     6.526798372448609`*^-6 I, 
    0.00038469551764633357` - 0.00001404116826826714` I, 
    0.001701560346692065` - 
     0.00028186563718451556` I, -0.0036157861645215892` - 
     0.0014334932215780709` I, 
    0.001701560346692065` - 0.00028186563718451556` I, 
    0.00038469551764633357` - 
     0.00001404116826826714` I}, {0.00038469551764633357` - 
     0.00001404116826826714` I, 
    0.0006174506610746909` - 0.0000362484579179957` I, 
    0.004451276746846666` - 
     0.008110956245960126` I, -0.0018348493676154623` - 
     0.0003292738942473982` I, 
    0.004451276746846666` - 0.008110956245960126` I, 
    0.0006174506610746909` - 
     0.0000362484579179957` I}, {0.001701560346692065` - 
     0.00028186563718451556` I, 
    0.004451276746846666` - 
     0.008110956245960126` I, -0.0016630055874367914` - 
     0.0002688975828702291` I, -0.0013951809613295997` - 
     0.00018777972040581582` I, -0.0016630055874367914` - 
     0.0002688975828702291` I, 
    0.004451276746846666` - 
     0.008110956245960126` I}, {-0.0036157861645215892` - 
     0.0014334932215780709` I, -0.0018348493676154623` - 
     0.0003292738942473982` I, -0.0013951809613295997` - 
     0.00018777972040581582` I, -0.001649644339494305` - 
     0.0002644804933021536` I, -0.0013951809613295997` - 
     0.00018777972040581582` I, -0.0018348493676154623` - 
     0.0003292738942473982` I}, {0.001701560346692065` - 
     0.00028186563718451556` I, 
    0.004451276746846666` - 
     0.008110956245960126` I, -0.0016630055874367914` - 
     0.0002688975828702291` I, -0.0013951809613295997` - 
     0.00018777972040581582` I, -0.0016630055874367914` - 
     0.0002688975828702291` I, 
    0.004451276746846666` - 
     0.008110956245960126` I}, {0.00038469551764633357` - 
     0.00001404116826826714` I, 
    0.0006174506610746909` - 0.0000362484579179957` I, 
    0.004451276746846666` - 
     0.008110956245960126` I, -0.0018348493676154623` - 
     0.0003292738942473982` I, 
    0.004451276746846666` - 0.008110956245960126` I, 
    0.0006174506610746909` - 
     0.0000362484579179957` I}}, {{0.00026221806120695063` - 
     9.132096056088802`*^-6 I, 
    0.00038420480406961213` - 0.000019632560501338157` I, 
    0.0016590243195173551` - 
     0.00038474728620012356` I, -0.0031986954042854928` - 
     0.0017753902359875918` I, 
    0.0016590243195173551` - 0.00038474728620012356` I, 
    0.00038420480406961213` - 
     0.000019632560501338157` I}, {0.00038420480406961213` - 
     0.000019632560501338157` I, 
    0.0006154214640650449` - 0.00005058106279201534` I, 
    0.002561455035228608` - 
     0.0065343476170139` I, -0.0017814909478848769` - 
     0.00044757780189576285` I, 
    0.002561455035228608` - 0.0065343476170139` I, 
    0.0006154214640650449` - 
     0.00005058106279201534` I}, {0.0016590243195173551` - 
     0.00038474728620012356` I, 
    0.002561455035228608` - 
     0.0065343476170139` I, -0.001623300348016125` - 
     0.0003674684922360431` I, -0.0013717502339991136` - 
     0.00025847659591489983` I, -0.001623300348016125` - 
     0.0003674684922360431` I, 
    0.002561455035228608` - 
     0.0065343476170139` I}, {-0.0031986954042854928` - 
     0.0017753902359875918` I, -0.0017814909478848769` - 
     0.00044757780189576285` I, -0.0013717502339991136` - 
     0.00025847659591489983` I, -0.0016108898926981722` - 
     0.0003615740196760342` I, -0.0013717502339991136` - 
     0.00025847659591489983` I, -0.0017814909478848769` - 
     0.00044757780189576285` I}, {0.0016590243195173551` - 
     0.00038474728620012356` I, 
    0.002561455035228608` - 
     0.0065343476170139` I, -0.001623300348016125` - 
     0.0003674684922360431` I, -0.0013717502339991136` - 
     0.00025847659591489983` I, -0.001623300348016125` - 
     0.0003674684922360431` I, 
    0.002561455035228608` - 
     0.0065343476170139` I}, {0.00038420480406961213` - 
     0.000019632560501338157` I, 
    0.0006154214640650449` - 0.00005058106279201534` I, 
    0.002561455035228608` - 
     0.0065343476170139` I, -0.0017814909478848769` - 
     0.00044757780189576285` I, 
    0.002561455035228608` - 0.0065343476170139` I, 
    0.0006154214640650449` - 0.00005058106279201534` I}}};

g = 1.5*1590/10; \[Beta] = 1./(8.617333262145 10^-2 70); niw=4; nk=6;

(* A good starting guess for FindRoot may be the initial step of an iterative solution*)
\[CapitalSigma]Arr = -(g^2/\[Beta]) ListConvolve[DqArr, 
    G0Arr, {{-1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 
      1}}];(*Keeps track of the fact that mesh on indices 2,3 is periodic but \
mesh on 1 is not, so the range is diff from the domain*)
\[CapitalSigma]Arr = 
  CenterArray[\[CapitalSigma]Arr, G0Arr // Dimensions, 
   0. + 0. I];(*Pad with zeros on the tails of the first index to get same \
shape as G0Arr*)

SArr = Table[Subscript[S, n, kx, 
   ky], {n, -niw, niw - 1}, {kx, 0, 2 - 2/nk, 2/nk}, {ky, 0, 2 - 2/nk,
     2/nk}];
eqArr = (Flatten[(SArr + 
       CenterArray[
        g^2/\[Beta] ListConvolve[DqArr, 1./(
          1./G0Arr - SArr), {{-1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}], 
        G0Arr // Dimensions])] == 
    ConstantArray[0. + 0. I, 2 niw*nk^2]) // Thread;

FindRoot[eqArr, {Flatten[SArr], Flatten[\[CapitalSigma]Arr]} // 
  Transpose]


Works for me in 14.0 on Windows 10, resulting in {Subscript[S, -4, 0, 0] -> 0. + 0. I,   Subscript[S, -4, 0, 1/3] -> 0. + 0.  I,...,Subscript[S, -2, 0, 0] -> -17.7417 +    1.81377 I, Subscript[S, -2, 0, 1/3] -> -14.9386 +    1.45045 I, Subscript[S, -2, 0, 2/3] -> -18.9266 + 2.79704  I,...,Subscript[S, 3, 5/3, 4/3] -> 0. + 0. I,   Subscript[S, 3, 5/3, 5/3] -> 0. + 0. I} with Timing in 1.84375s.

@user64494 Thanks for confirming that the minimal working code does work on your system. The reason it takes 1.84s to solve this is because it has to solve  288 equations in 288 variables numerically, rather than 1 tensor equation in 1 tensor variable. The goal is to make it work without unpacking the tensor into a vector, so that optimized algorithms for tensor convolutions can speed up the solution drastically.

The FindRoot function is used to numerically find a root of a system of equations. However, your usage of FindRoot seems to have some issues regarding the syntax and the way you're defining your equation.
Assuming you want to find the values of SArr and ΣArr that satisfy the equation you provided, you can define your equation first and then use FindRoot to find its roots.
Here's how you can do it:
eqn[SArr_?MatrixQ, ΣArr_?MatrixQ] := 
 SArr == CenterArray[-(g^2/β) ListConvolve[DqArr, 1./(1./G0Arr - SArr), {{-1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}], 
   Dimensions[G0Arr]]

initialGuess = {SArr0, ΣArr0}; (* Provide initial guess for SArr and ΣArr *)

solution = FindRoot[eqn[SArr, ΣArr], initialGuess]

Here's what each part of the code does:

eqn[SArr, ΣArr] defines your equation. This function takes matrices SArr and ΣArr as inputs and returns the equation you provided.

initialGuess provides an initial guess for the values of SArr and ΣArr. This should be a list of initial guesses for each variable.

FindRoot[eqn[SArr, ΣArr], initialGuess] uses FindRoot to find the roots of the equation defined by eqn. It starts the search from the initial guess provided by initialGuess.


Replace SArr0 and ΣArr0 with your initial guesses for SArr and ΣArr, respectively.
Ensure that DqArr and G0Arr are properly defined before running this code. Also, make sure that the dimensions of DqArr and G0Arr match the expected dimensions in the convolution operation.

thanks for taking the time to engage with the problem. If I try your code with the sample arrays provided in the minimal working code, Mathematica throws the error "Value [CapitalSigma]Arr0 in search specification {SArr0,
[CapitalSigma]Arr0} is not a number or array of numbers". Could you please try what you're suggesting at your end?
The call to FindRoot you propose is strange because there is no way for Mathematica to know which variable to solve for. In any case, SArr was intended as the tensor to solve for, and ΣArr, the initial guess.
